# Print 2 closest, smaller Fibonacci numbers

Tags: java, fibonacci

I am having a hard time figuring out the solution to this problem. I need to write an iterative (can't use recursion) solution to a problem in which a user inputs a number via scanner (for example, 10) and it prints 2 "previous" Fib numbers.

For the input "10" example, it would be:

```
5
8
```

As they're the "biggest" two Fib numbers prior to 10.

If the input is 13, it would print:

```
8
13
```

As 13 is a Fib number itself, it prints only 1 number prior, and then itself.

Now I know how to iteratevely find the "n-th" Fib number but I can't get my mind around a solution to run til a given number (rather than the n-th Fib number) and somehow print only the last 2 before it (or, if the given number is a Fib number by itself, count that as one too).

Now I'm aware of the formula that uses the perfect square - but unfortunately, can't use that...

Edit as it made some people confused:

I do not ask for a code, nor do I want anyone to solve this for me. I just genuinely want to understand how to approach such questions.

Edit #2:

Here's a code I wrote:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;

while (a < num) {
    int temp = a;
    a = a + b;
    b = temp;
}
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(a);
```

The problem I'm having is that if the num input is indeed a Fib num - it will work as intended, otherwise, it prints 1 prior Fib num and the next one, so for input "10" it prints 8 and 13.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework-writing service.  If you think we are going to do your homework for you, then you are sorely mistaken.  [An open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @JoeC While I highly understand your point and the letter, I did made the research and I'm aware of the different approaches. I do not ask for a complete code, just help in understanding the right approach and how to deal with this kind of problems.

Comment: Then you need to [edit] your question to show all of this.  As it stands, this appears to be a "gimme teh codez" question, and without evidence that effort has been made, you risk it being closed as such.

Comment: My approach -- work out the logic on paper *extensively* before even considering writing code. Play with the math, go through reams of paper, and it usually comes to you.

Comment: I don't get the problem. You said you already have a formula for computing all Fibs iterative. Then just do so and stop when arriving at some Fib greater equals the input. When that happens, output the last two computed Fibs that you always memorize alongside. If that description doesn't help, you probably want a **specific solution**. But this is only possible if you show us your code first.

Comment: So for 5 and 8 being the numbers below the threshold of 10 - how do you know, that there isn't another one below or equal to 10?

Comment: I know how to determine if a number is a Fib number, 5*n*n + 4 or 5*n*n - 4 are a perfect square, therefor the n is a Fib number. I'm also aware that there are more Fib numbers below or equal to 10. I just don't understand how would you save the last two, or how to "memorize alongside" as @Zabuza suggested.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, callback if still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

You said that you already have a method that computes the `n`-th Fibonacci number iterative. Since Fibonacci numbers are usually defined based on the last two Fibonacci elements, you should also already have them at hand, see the definition from Wikipedia:

[image: Fibonacci definition]

The only thing you need to do is to run your iterative method until you reach the input. And then output the current memorized values for `F_(n - 1)` and `F_(n - 2)` (or `F_n` if equal to input).

---

### Example

Suppose you have a Fibonacci method like (which I grabbed from the first google result)

```
public static long fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 2) {
        return (n > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    long fib1 = 0;
    long fib2 = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        final long newFib = fib1 + fib2;
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = newFib;
    }
    return fib2;
}
```

You need to modify it to accept the `input` and return both last Fibonacci numbers `fib1` and `fib2`. Replace the loop to `n` by an infinite loop from which you break once exceeding `input`:

```
public static long[] fib(long input) {
    // Special cases
    if (input == 1) {
        return new long[] { 1l, 1l };
    }
    if (input == 0) {
        return new long[] { 0l };
    }
    if (input < 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // Seed values
    long fib1 = 0;
    long fib2 = 1;

    // Repeat until return
    while (true) {
        long newFib = fib1 + fib2;

        // Reached the end
        if (newFib >= input) {
            // Push 'newFib' to the results
            if (newFib == input) {
                fib1 = fib2;
                fib2 = newFib;
            }
            return new long[] { fib1, fib2 };
        }

        // Prepare next round
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = newFib;
    }
}
```

The method now returns at `[0]` the second to nearest Fibonacci and at `[1]` the nearest Fibonacci number to `input`.

You can easily adjust your own method likewise using this example.

---

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] results = fib(20L);
    // Prints "8, 13"
    System.out.println(results[0] + ", " + results[1]);

    results = fib(21L);
    // Prints "13, 21"
    System.out.println(results[0] + ", " + results[1]);
}
```

---

### Another example

A different view to the same problem can be obtained by using some kind of `nextFib` method. Then you can repeatedly pick until exceeding `input`. Therefore, we build some class like

```
public class FibonacciCalculator {
    private long fib1 = 0;
    private long fib2 = 1;
    private int n = 0;

    public long nextFib() {
        // Special cases
        if (n <= 2) {
            long result = (n > 0) ? 1 : 0;
            // Increase the index
            n++;
            return result;
        }

        // Compute current and push
        long newFib = fib1 + fib2;
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = newFib;

        return newFib;
    }
}
```

And then we just call it until we exceed `input`, always memorizing the last two values:

```
public static long[] fib(long input) {
    FibonacciCalculator calc = new FibonacciCalculator();
    long lastFib = 0L;
    long secondToLastFib = 0L;

    while (true) {
        long curFib = calc.nextFib();

        if (curFib > input) {
            return new long[] { secondToLastFib, lastFib };
        } else if (curFib == input) {
            return new long[] { lastFib, curFib };
        }

        secondToLastFib = lastFib;
        lastFib = curFib;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I wrote something like this: `  int a = 0;
  int b = 1;

  while (a < num) {
   int temp = a;
   a = a + b;
   b = temp;
  }
  System.out.println(b);
  System.out.println(a);` but instead of printing 2 prior Fibs, it wrote 1 that comes before it and 1 after the input number. It does however work if the input num is a Fib num itself. I honestly don't know where my problem is.

Comment: Instead of posting code in the comment section, post a link to some website with code formatting. Or edit your question. The problem is obvious, you always delete the `secondToLast` fib, even if `a` is strictly greater than `num`. You should retain it in that case (see the `if` statements in my examples).

Comment: I edited my original post. Unfortunately, I still can't tell what my problem is...

Comment: Maybe it helps if you write the algorithm execution on paper for a small number. If `a` strictly exceeds `num` (`a > num`) then you already have set `a` to that bigger number. So, when you leave the loop, `a` is that bigger number. But you only want that in the case `a == num`, else you don't want `a` to be the bigger number. You can fix this by either checking the condition inside the loop (and then refuse to assign `a` to the bigger number) or memorizing the last three fibs instead of the last two. Then you can fall back to `{fib2, fib3}` instead of `{fib1, fib2}` if `fib1` exceeds `num`.